# Split the elements in the arraylist to two more list

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

subjectList =    [ITC102 Coding , ITC106 Programming , ITC206 Java , MGT100 Management]

This is the arraylist that i want to split into two sub arraylist.

I want to make two new arrays subCode and subName.

subcode = [ITC102 , ITC106 , ITC206 , MGT100]
subName = [Coding , Programming , Java , Management]

I tried .sublist but it sublists the whole list instead of the data inside each list.

Comment: So what did you try before posting the question that failed?

Comment: Do you have a code that you may show us?

Comment: Can you please be more specific than "it is not working"? That tells us pretty much nothing about the actual problem being faced.

Comment: The program above is working but i can't get to split that arraylist so that i can store the 1st word of every element into one list and all the other words to another list. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Answer (score 0):

If in every record there are only two words separated by space then you can do something like below:

```
List<String> list =new ArrayList<String>();
        list.add("ITC102 Coding");
        list.add("ITC106 Programming");
        list.add("ITC206 Java");
        list.add("MGT100 Management");

        List<String> subcode  =new ArrayList<String>();
        List<String> subName =new ArrayList<String>();

        for(String str:list)
        {
            String strArray[]=str.split(" ");
            subcode.add(strArray[0]);
            subName.add(strArray[1]);
        }
```